# I would like to insert a counter inside an index in LaTeX

Tags: indexing, counters

This is my first question on Stackexchange, please apologize if I am too naive!

In my lecture notes, I am inserting exercises in the text.
They have a specific counter, say \ExoCounter.
I am using a command

```
\def\Exo#1{%
  \stepcounter{ExoCounter}% 
  \index[exo]{\theExoCounter~#1}%
  {\bf \textbf{Exercise}~\theExoCounter}~\textbf{#1}\par%
  }
```

#1 is the title of the exercise, to be also included in an index, via

```
\index[exo]{\theExoCounter~#1}
```

where the exercises index was created in the beginning of the main file:

```
\newindex{exo}{edx}{end}{Exercise Index}
```

In the source file, when I use the command

```
\Exo{Critical exponent of the susceptibility}
blah blah blah
```

say at page 16 in the output file, then

```
\Exo{Critical exponent of the critical isotherm}
blah blah blah
```

at page 17 of the output file, etc and run the make index,
it produces an index file with

```
  \item \theExoCounter ~Critical exponent of the critical isotherm, 17
  \item \theExoCounter ~Critical exponent of the susceptibility, 16
```

i.e.  the command \theExoCounter is taken "verbatim" and it delivers in the Exercise Index the output

> 27 Critical exponent of the critical isotherm, 17

> 27 Critical exponent of the susceptibility, 16

etc instead of

> 1 Critical exponent of the susceptibility, 16

> 2 Critical exponent of the critical isotherm, 17

if I have altogether 27 exercises. One thing is the alphabetic order instead of the chronological order in the index,
but this is not the main point here. My first worry is that the command \theExoCounter in the \index command
is interpreted only at the end of compilation, when the index is created, and the counter already has its final value, here 27.

When the command \index[exo]{\theExoCounter~#1} is called in the macro \Exo, I would like to replace the value of the counter
in the index by its *current* numerical value.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Could you put this all together into a single MWE that we could copy and paste?  (And unrelated: `\bf` became `\bfseries` in the 90s.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `imakeidx` package instead of `index` package. And you can use another argument to define which alphabet this index belong to. I add a style file (exostyle.ist) to customize your index appearance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\newcounter{ExoCounter}
\def\Exo#1#2{%
\stepcounter{ExoCounter}%
\index[exo]{#1@\theExoCounter~#2}%
{\bfseries Exercise~\theExoCounter~#2}%
}
\makeindex[name=exo,columns=1, options= -s exostyle.ist, title=The index of Exercises]
\begin{filecontents}{exostyle.ist}
headings_flag 1

heading_prefix "\n\\centering\\large\\sffamily\\bfseries%
\\noindent\\textbf{"heading_suffix "}\\par\\vspace{0.5cm}\\nopagebreak"

item_0 "\n \\item "

delim_0 " \\hfill "
delim_1 " \\hfill "
delim_2 " \\hfill "
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]\Exo{s}{susceptibility}
\clearpage
\lipsum[1]\Exo{c}{critical isotherm}
\clearpage
\printindex[exo]
\end{document}
```

[image]